# Isnull and data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose I have a table like:

```
Tab(MyDate datetime null, MyIs bit null, ...)
```

Then I have SQL Like

```
    select Isnull(MyDate, 1), IsNull(MyIs, 999) from Tab;
```

If `MyDate`, `MyIs` value is `null` in DB, the result is:

```
    MyDate                   MyIs  
    1900-01-02 00:00:00.000  1
```

Not the expected value like

```
MyDate        MyIs  
1             999
```

So it looks like the return value is based on data type of the column.
How to resolve this issue?

For my testing case as above, I Only got one row from the table.

Comment: What happens if some rows have valid dates - what's the datatype of the date column then?

Comment: if there is no null value, it is fine.

Comment: `MyDate` is returned as one day after the beginning of time, as requested.  `MyIs` is the value other than 0.  There aren't a lot of choices when you're a `BIT`.  If you `CAST` `MyIs` to an `INT` then you can get your desired result.  A `DATETIME` simply isn't going to be 1 unless you always choose to display it as the number of days since BoT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're looking for, you don't.

All the values in the same column *must* be the same data type.  If your data had NOT NULL values in some rows *(returning the column's data-type)* and NULL values in other rows *(returning a different data type, as per your `CASE` statement)*, you would break this requirement.

You could have two extra fields...

```
select
  MyDate,
  CASE WHEN MyDate IS NULL THEN 1   ELSE 0 END As MyDateWibble,
  MyIs,
  CASE WHEN MyIs   IS NULL THEN 999 ELSE 0 END AS MyIsWibble
FROM
  Tab;
```

You could `CAST()` everything to `VARCHAR()` and return strings instead of `DATETIME`, `BIT` or `INT`.

But, more probably, I'd review the reason you want to do this in the first place and work out an alternative design.

Comment: Thank you. What I did for this is to compare the value. I use something like: isnull(a.MyDate,1) <> isnull(b.MyDate,1), then I found there is problem with null value for some cases.

Comment: @KentZhou - Why are you trying to do that? If you want to compare this field in a join, use this instead... `NOT(a.MyDate = b.MyDate OR (a.MyDate IS NULL AND b.MyDate IS NULL))` It's not as short as you have, but it works. The `ISNULL()` approach requires you to use replacement values that *can not* appear elsewhere in the data, and for those values ot be the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the datatypes.

For example, when you test for the data you return *integer* 1. 
This will get translated to the data where sql server starts to count from + 1 (day)

Comment: The OP already knows that much `So it looks like the return value is based on data type of the column.`  But the question is `How to resolve this issue?`  To which the answer is probably `Change your requirements.`

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
select 
    case when mydate is null
    then '1' else cast(mydate as varchar(40))
    end,
    case when MyIs is null
    then 999 else MyIs
    end
from tab
```

[image]

Comment: The OP doesn't want a date to appear in row 1 column 1.  The op want the number 1 to appear there.  A completely different data type from what the op wants to appear in row 2 column 1.  Which isn't possible.

Comment: thanks for the heads up dems, I did not realize that. I changes the sql casting to string. I think it solves the OPs problem. There is the detail of the date format but it can be changes as he needs.

Comment: fyi, as I understand, when the date is valid, he wants the date on the valid format

Comment: This now mimics what the OP asked for, but by changing the datatype of the column to a VARCHAR(). As for what the OP actually wants, based on a comment to my answer, I think the OP is actually just looking for a short-hand way of doing `a.MyDate <> b.MyDate` but allowing for `NULL` being the same as `NULL`.  I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: Indeed I am. But that's the only way of having 2 different "data types" on the same column, return everything as string

Answer (score 0):

SQL servers "zero" date or base date is 1900-01-01 so you are just converting `MYDate` null with 1 so it is adding 1 day in base date as

```
declare @d datetime = 1
select @d

1900-01-02 00:00:00.000

set @d = 0
select @d

1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

`MyIs` is a bit type so anything except 0 is '1' like

```
declare @b bit = 0
select @b

set @b = 1
select @b

set @b = -1
select @b
```

Above behavior of columns because of different `data types`

Comment: The OP already knows the cause of the behaviour `So it looks like the return value is based on data type of the column.` The OP is looking for a work around. This just explains what the OP already worked out.

Comment: @Dems you are right and because you have already answered that part so I did not do that.